# Can I directly append return function calls in Arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function that calls other functions that returns an object.
I tried appending the return values of these functions using this format of code:

in my `model`:

```
def get_cinfo(id)
  return Client.find(id)
end

def get_caddress(id)
  return Client.find(id).addresses
end

def get_cpolicies(id)
  return Client.find(id).policies
end

def get_ccontactinfo(id)
  return Client.find(id).contact_informations
end

def generate_client(id)
 client = Array.new
 client << get_cinfo(id) << get_caddress(id) << get_ccontactinfo(id)
end
```

where:
get_cinfo , get_caddress and get_ccontactinfo are functions returning a single or two instance

The error produced: [get_cinfo...] variable is undefined.

Why is this happening? Are Function calls not directly allowed in appending to arrays?

Edit: I tried adding `self.` to each function and it worked. I was wondering though, what if I didn't want to add self to that function so that it remains protected -- anyways I'm not planning to call it (yet) directly for any other reason than calling those functions in that particular function A.

Comment: Where are you placing this code? Mode, controller, somewhere else?

Comment: .self if you are calling as class method.

Comment: @iGian hi yes this code is in the model

Comment: It seems like you defined these as instance methods in the `Client` model. If you want to call them like `Client.generate_client(42)` you would have to define them as class methods (sometimes called static methods). You can do so by writing `def self.get_cinfo(id)`, ..., `def self.generate_client(id)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also if you mix multiple data types / models in the result of `generate_client` you should consider not to use an array but a hash - there you can name the properties properly and don't have to rely on the order in which you put in the informations so much.

Comment: @JaySchneider thanks for explaining why I should use hash for these I'll read up further since orderwise I need them to appear as appended (that's why I used array) so every array is a row and every array inside the parent array is a column - for generating excel

Comment: @JaySchneider I did edit that I used self and it worked. I just understood now how you word it how it is different from a function without self (i can only use it if I'm working on the instance not on itself. huhu) thanks a lot. I'm a java a python programmer and just dived into ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `client` first with its value. On `generate_client`:

```
client = []
client << get_cinfo(id) << get_caddress(id) << get_ccontactinfo(id)
return client
```

Comment: forgot to edit that but its there mine has `client = Array.new`

Comment: Good catch! But it doesn't explain the error: `[get_cinfo...] variable is undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to even create the array and then append to it individually, as both can be done together:

```
def generate_client(id)
 [get_cinfo(id), get_caddress(id), get_ccontactinfo(id)]
end
```

This will return the array, without an extra method calls. Method calls being appended is perfectly acceptable anyways. If in your example the value in the array is `nil`, it is not the case of the array being created in `generate_client`, but more likely the value being returned by the function call.

Comment: Any particular reason for the random down-vote? Is there something incorrect?